# Why doesn't my SQLite database add data until I close my application?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

My Delphi application is using FireDac and an SQLite database. I've noticed that updates are being saved in a journal file and the database file is not actually updated until I close my application.

The application is making lots of 'batch updates' to the database. Each individual update is inside a TFDQuery.StartTransaction ... TFDQuery.Commit pair. Despite this, it seems all updates are held in the journal file until the application ends.

How can I force SQLite to update the database after each batch of updates rather than when my application finishes?

I've tried changing the SQLite db to WAL but the same thing happens.

Despite using 'StartTransaction' and 'Commit' the data stays in the journal until the application ends.

```
try
  Query.Connection := FDConnection1;
  FDConnection1.Open;
  FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
  Query.SQL.Text := 'select 1 from t_Manufacturers where m_Name = ' + QuotedStr(ManString);
  Query.Open;
  if Query.RecordCount = 0 then begin
    { not found, so add }
    Query.SQL.Text := 'insert into t_Manufacturers (m_Name, m_ManUID) values (:Name, null)';
    Query.ParamByName('Name').AsString := ManString;
    Query.ExecSQL;
    { save m_ManUID for logging }
    Query.SQL.Text := 'select m_ManUID from t_Manufacturers where m_Name = ' + QuotedStr(ManString);
    Query.Open;
  end;
  Result := Query.FieldByName(m_ManUID).AsInteger;
  FDConnection1.Commit;
except
  on E : EDatabaseError do begin
    MessageDlg('Database error adding manufacturer: ' + E.Message, mtError, [mbOk], 0);
    FDConnection1.Rollback;
  end;
```

No error messages or issues. Providing the application finishes OK, the database is updated as expected, so I'm happy that my programming and SQL is doing exactly what I need in that respect.

Comment: Sorry Steve, deleted my answer to your post. You where totally right, my fault. Seeams to be a Porblem with SQL Lite. please look at: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC
SQLLite Driver is configured by default to provide high performance. Look at section "Using SQLite Database" position 4-6 may be helpfull

Comment: Set the LockingMode in the Options property to lmNormal, if it is not already

Comment: Dave - Thanks. I checked and it is set to lmNormal.

Answer (score 1):

It is very dubious that "*it seems all updates are held in the journal file until the application ends*". SQLite3 is very serious about writing data - more serious than most DB engines I know. Just check https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html

I suspect you are somewhat confused by the presence of the journal file. After a transaction, the journal file is still kept there on disk, ready for any new write operation. But the data is actually written in the main file.

Just write some data, then kill the application before closing it (using the task manager). Then re-open the file (re-start the app): I am almost sure you will see the data properly stored.

FireDAC is "cheating" with the default journalization mode, for best performance. It uses some default values which may be confusing. As stated by [FireDAC documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC): *Set LockingMode to Normal to enable shared DB access. Set Synchronous to Normal or Full to make committed data visible to others.*

Comment: This behaviour is even documented in [Temporary Files Used by SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#rollback_journals). Rollback journal is not deleted at the end of transaction, if `locking_mode` is set to `EXCLUSIVE`, which it is by default in FireDAC.

Comment: Arnaud - thank you for this. I'm feeling a little silly now. I tried your suggestion and killed my application immediately after the call to 'Commit'. As you suggested, the journal file is still there, but the data has been added to the database. I had been fooled by just happening to have an explorer window open which showed the presence of the journal file as my application was running.

Comment: Peter - thanks for that. I had seen that before, but a second reading has helped me understand this much better.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `FDConnection1.StartTransaction;` In this state condition, the transaction is still on the memory (cache) without any end. Therefore, you need to end your transaction with `commit` command such like `FDConnection1.Commit;`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do already have the FDConnection1.Commit - immediately before the except block.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I went back to basics and wrote a test application with all the database activity confined to a single procedure fired by a button click. In that procedure I added multiple rows to a table using a for loop.

The for loop is surrounded by *StartTransaction* and *Commit* calls. Running through the code in the debugger, the journal file is created on the first call to ExecSQL. However, the file remains there after the loop has completed and *Commit* has been called.

The database is only updated and the journal file deleted when *Close* is called at the end of the procedure.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Query  : TFDQuery;
  Index  : Integer;
begin
  FDConnection1.DriverName := 'SQLite';
  FDConnection1.Params.Values['Database'] := 'C:\Testing\test.db';
  FDConnection1.Open;
  Query := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  Query.Connection := FDConnection1;
  try
    FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
    for Index := 1 to 10 do begin
      Query.SQL.Text := 'insert into Table1 (Name, IDNum) values (:Name, :IDNum)';
      Query.ParamByName('Name').AsString := 'Test_Manufacturer_' + IntToStr(Index);
      Query.ParamByName('IDNum').AsInteger := Index;
      Query.ExecSQL;
    end;
    FDConnection1.Commit;
  except
    on E : EDatabaseError do begin
      MessageDlg('Database error adding manufacturer: ' + E.Message, mtError, [mbOk], 0);
      FDConnection1.Rollback;
    end;
  end;
  Query.Destroy;
  FDConnection1.Close;
end;
```

I'm suspecting that I have another connection to the database open within my application and that might be stopping the update until the application closes. However, I'm still not understanding why the call to Commit isn't updating the database at the end of the transaction block.

Comment: That behavior sounds like the commit is instead creating a savepoint. And that seems to be [the default firedac behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/e/index.php?title=Managing_Transactions_\(FireDAC\)#Nested_Transactions) when starting a transaction when you already have one open. I'd look into finding stray `StartTransaction` calls.

Comment: Or you're using Wal mode where that's normal behavior.

Comment: Shawn, thanks for the reply. I'll have a trawl through my code to see if that might be the case.

Comment: Shawn, just to confirm, WAL not being used.