# My SQLite database data is back to the state of the previous day, how to prevent this?

Tags: sqlite

I have a point of sale program that has been working for some clients for about 4 years, as I needed it to work offline I opted to use SQLite, which works very well for me. In one of my clients, after a power outage, the data that had been registered on the current day "disappeared" and the database stayed with the state of the previous day, even the auto-increment fields came back too.
I use SQLite version 3 and use journal_mode = DELETE.
I wanted to know if there is something that prevents this or what could have caused this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite is designed to maintain a consistent state of the DB, even after a power outage.
When accessing the DB the first time after the outage, Sqlite must have found the presence of a journal file with uncommitted transactions and rolled them back to the start of the transaction.

From the description of your problem, apparently the start of the uncommitted transaction was at the start of the day.

This seems to indicate that your program opens a transaction when the program is started and closes it when the program is correctly closed.
This means that all the changes are stored in the rollback journal and written to the database only after gracefully closing the program.

If this is true, you need to change the program to open a transaction (with BEGIN TRANSACTION) only when you have some data to write and close it (with COMMIT) immediately after completion.

If this is what you think your program is already doing, I would check if there is somewhere a query or a condition where BEGIN TRANSACTION is issued but not followed by any COMMIT.

To help you debug your program, note that when journal_mode is set to DELETE, the journal file is deleted at the end of any transaction. So if at any time you see a file in the same directory as the database file with the same name as the database file except with the 8 characters "-journal" appended, this means that there is an open transaction waiting to be either committed or rolled back. This file should persist only for long write transactions or when the program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Delphi's Firedac component to make this SQLite database connection and manipulation, based on past information I decided to research more and what I ended up concluding is that Firedac tries to "trick" SQLite to get more performance with its settings default, even using the Firedac component's StartTransaction and Commit methods, which I expected to match SQLite's BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT commands.
I found some information in the following link that helped me: [Why doesn't my SQLite database add data until I close my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554209/why-doesnt-my-sqlite-database-add-data-until-i-close-my-application)

What I needed to do was change the Synchronous property to Full.